# Ruby activerecord with Postgresql adapter can't select OID

Tags: ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I'm new to Ruby and ActiveRecord, so if this is a dumb question...sorry.

I have a Postgres database table that has path names in it. I need to be to do a find on a specific path and get the OID (the table is defined with: set_default_oids = true). The problem is that I can add a select("oid,path") but I never get the OID. I do get the path, but I need the OID.

I am assuming that there's some adapter option, or option for the table class, to say: Use OIDs, but I haven't been able to find it.

When I look at a result from a find, I can look at the object_id, but that appears to be something internal to ActiveRecord and has nothing to do with the OID. When using psql I can do:

```
db=# SELECT oid,path FROM path_table;
```

And I see the correct OIDs. So I know they're there...

Any suggestions?

Rob

Comment: If you look at `Model.columns.map(&:name)` in the Rails console, does it mention the `oid` column? What happens if you do `Model.select('oid').map(&:oid)`? By `Model` I mean whatever the model wrapper for your table is called.

Comment: I did just figure out that I can use connection.execute() and get it, but I would still like to see if there's a way to set up the class or connection so that I don't have to use the "raw" connection.

Comment: I tried: PathTable.select("oid,path").where("path = '/data/tables/2008/05/13'").map(&:oid) and got: "17341" which is the correct OID, but it seems to ignore the "path" portion of the select.

Comment: And, to answer your other question: If I do PathTable.columns.map(&:name), oid is NOT listed.

Comment: Maybe it would be better to use simple `SERIAL` field instead of internal `oid`s ?

Comment: I don't have control over the definition of the database tables. And the OIDs from the path table are used in the file tables, so I have to be able to get them.

Comment: No OID in `PathTable.columns` indicates that ActiveRecord's auto-schema discovery mechanism doesn't find OID (this isn't surprising). `PathTable.select("oid,path").where("path = '/data/tables/2008/05/13'").map(&:oid)` is just extracting the `oid`, if you `.map(&:path)` you'd see the path.

Comment: Have you tried using [`default_scope`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Default/ClassMethods/default_scope) to manually add the `oid` to the selected columns? I'm not sure if it will work or not but shouldn't take more than a couple minutes to try it out.

Comment: I tried: class PathTable < ActiveRecord::Base
irb(main):006:1> default_scope :select => "oid, path"
irb(main):007:1> end
=> [{:select=>"oid, path"}]
irb(main):008:0> PathTable.where("path = '/data/tables/2008/05/13'")
=> [#<PathTable path: "/data/tables/2008/05/13">]. So using select doesn't work. And when I tried :include => :oid, I just kept getting errors.

Comment: Can you add that to the question? Kinda' hard to read without any formatting.

Comment: Sorry, I've tried to format it, but it just keeps coming out all bunched up. At any rate, I've given up on ActiveRecord and am using the PG interface instead. If I have to jump through hoops to get ActiveRecord to work, I might as well just use SQL...

Answer (score 1):

I will be using the PG interface instead since using ActiveRecord doesn't seem to easily allow me to see the OIDs.